# Construct File Path using Java

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to create a file, but file path is constructed through String Concats that uses some internal variables and labels, I am getting following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect
    at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.createFileExclusively(Native Method)
    at java.io.File.createNewFile(Unknown Source)
    at CopyEJ.CopyEJ.main(CopyEJ.java:133)
```

Is there a standard approach to built such files ?

```
String s_path = text_dir + "\\" + time_stmp + "_" + "Session" + "_" + file_name;


        File ssw = new File(s_path);

        ssw.createNewFile();  //Errors Out here
```

Comment: kindly debug and observe path of s_path variable

Comment: Looks like The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect :)

Comment: please use System.getParameter("file.separator") and System.getParameter("path.separator") not "\\" strings...

Comment: Consider using `/` all the time since it's OS-independent and works on all operating systems.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-construct-a-file-path-in-java/

Comment: What does `text_dir` contain ? What does `time_stmp` contain? What does `file_name` contain? Write actual value of `s_path` here, please. And use java.io.File.separator instead of slashes and backslashes to construct path.

Comment: Rather than "\\" you should really use `File.separator` (as seen at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#separator), which is platform independent.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you:

```
String path = "D://abc" + filename+ ".txt";
System.out.println("Path--- " + path);
File file = new File(path);
file.createNewFile()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create the folder (*directory*) first:

```
String s_path = text_dir + "/" + time_stmp + "_" + "Session" + "_" + file_name;
File ssw = new File(s_path);

ssw.getParentFile().mkdirs();
ssw.createNewFile();
```

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Java  1.7 you can rewrite it as follows:

```
Path s_path = Paths.get(text_dir, time_stmp + "_" + "Session" + "_" + file_name);
Files.createDirectories(s_path.getParent());  
File ssw = s_path.toFile();
ssw.createNewFile();
```

`Paths.get()` will use default system path separator.